# How do I create an xml document in python

Tags: python, xml

Here is my sample code:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import *
def make_xml():
    doc = Document()
    node = doc.createElement('foo')
    node.innerText = 'bar'
    doc.appendChild(node)
    return doc
if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_xml().writexml(sys.stdout)
```

when I run the above code I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<foo/>
```

I would like to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<foo>bar</foo>
```

I just guessed that there was an innerText property, it gives no compiler error, but does not seem to work... how do I go about creating a text node?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting an attribute on an object won't give a compile-time or a run-time error, it will just do nothing useful if the object doesn't access it (i.e. "`node.noSuchAttr = 'bar'`" would also not give an error).

Unless you need a specific feature of `minidom`, I would look at `ElementTree`:

```
import sys
from xml.etree.cElementTree import Element, ElementTree

def make_xml():
    node = Element('foo')
    node.text = 'bar'
    doc = ElementTree(node)
    return doc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_xml().write(sys.stdout)
```

Answer (score 13):

@Daniel

Thanks for the reply, I also figured out how to do it with the minidom (I'm not sure of the difference between the ElementTree vs the minidom)

```
from xml.dom.minidom import *
def make_xml():
    doc = Document();
    node = doc.createElement('foo')
    node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('bar'))
    doc.appendChild(node)
    return doc
if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_xml().writexml(sys.stdout)
```

I swear I tried this before posting my question...